# How can I improve my Twitter streaming crawler?

Tags: perl, twitter

I did a Twitter crawler using the Streaming API. It is programmed in perl using the [Net:Twitter:Stream](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/Net-Twitter-Stream/Net/Twitter/Stream.html). I think it is retrieving few tweets. I left it tracking TV series tweets last night and I got just 30860 tweets. I think it's a low value. 
What do you think about it? Is there any other perl library that I can use? 
I'll put part of my code here to see if there is something wrong.

Thanks everybody

Thiago

```
use JSON;
use Solr;
use Net::Twitter::Stream;
sub coletar{
    Net::Twitter::Stream->new ( user => $username, pass => $password,
                    callback => \&got_tweet,
                    connection_closed_cb => \&connection_closed,
                    track => $track); #$track has my string search;
    sub connection_closed {
        if ($count==0){
           sleep 10;
        }
        elsif($count==1){
           sleep 20;
        }
        else{
           sleep 240;
        }
        $count++;
        warn "Connection to Twitter closed";
        coletar();              #Recomeçando o download de tweets.
    }
    sub got_tweet {
        $cont=0;
        my ( $tweet, $json ) = @_; 
        # Here I save the tweet in my NoSQL database...
    }
}
coletar;
```

Comment: Your script does not contain any executing code, only subroutines. Your subroutines are also nested, which is not a good idea, and probably doesn't do what you think it does. You should avoid using prototypes unless you know what they do, e.g. `sub coletar { ... }`, and not `sub coletar () { ... }`. You should edit your question and include code that actually does something.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to call the function, but I do it in the end of the code. I changed coletar(){..} to coletar{...} and I don't see any diference. I'll update the question. But, it's working in the same way. Since last night until now, it colected 80319 tweets and I think it's a low value.

Comment: Did you try this module: AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream ? I saw them in action in Perl Mova.

Comment: I did another crawler using this AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream, but I think it's slower than Net::Twitter::Stream. Althought, this module is a bit diferent, I think I can use it with OAuth Access, but I don't know how to use it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to keep in mind about the Twitter stream. First of all, if your code is a bottleneck, the queue of incoming tweets will overflow and your connection will die. So it very well may not be your code.

Twitter is limiting the number of Tweets they give to "regular" consumers, and charging for full streams. So you may be hitting rate limits, but it's hard to be sure.

One way to test what percentage of tweets you are getting is to set up a second account that randomly sends tweets that should be caught in your filter. Then count the percentage of those Tweets that are caught in your scraper. If it is not 100%, you are probably getting rate limited.

Comment: OK. I'll try to do another account and test my crawler. But if I'm getting rate limited, is there anything I can do? I read something about a OAuth authentication but I don't exactly what is it.